# Using Angular Factory Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I'm trying to follow Code School's Staying Sharp with Angular Soup to Bits.
I've come to the point where I've created a note factory service and implement the `$resource` service.

I `$scope.notes = Note.query()` and then `console.log($scope.notes)` but nothing appears in my dev tools console of my browser. What am I doing wrong?

My GitHub repo with the latest commit where this is happening can be found [here](https://github.com/gh0st/StayingSharpWithAngularSTB/commit/343a8a9c46208cf8d51957b3d826e093590ed540).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `$resource` has implemented `$scope.notes = Note.query()` will assign data returned from ajax directly to `$scope.notes` variable once `Note.query()` promise gets resolved.

But the way you are doing is, you are expecting to get response from `async` call as soon as you make, for getting response in console you should wait till that promise gets resolved.

```
Note.query().$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.notes = response;
    console.log($scope.notes);
});
```

**Update**

The other problem was OP has mistakenly registered multiple instances of the `NotesIndexController` controller, because of which many controller are getting registered but last one controller instance got binded to view. By correcting all other controller name. This issue has been fixed.

Comment: No, there is nothing.

Comment: @gh0st are you sure, server does respond with records with that URL?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I tested it using `curl`.

Comment: @gh0st may I know what URL you used to `curl` it?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/notes returns all, http://localhost:8000/notes/1 returns note of ID 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106649/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-gh0st).